# Bionic Beaver offline need gcc

Tags: gcc

How can I build a C compiler while offline?
I have downloaded and transfered bison, make, build-utils, and dpkg yet without a gcc in this distro what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't build `gcc` without `gcc`. The `gcc` source code is heavily dependent on being compiled by `gcc`. If you just need a C compiler for small projects, you can transfer a small compiler like [`tcc`](https://bellard.org/tcc/), which can compile its own source code. It can't build `gcc`.